# Polymer Repeat over dictionary doesn't work for index

Tags: javascript, polymer, material-design

I've created my own polymer js elements, and am trying to do a `repeat` iteration over the index values in a dictionary.  Unfortunately I can't get it to repeat.

Here's my iterative-example.html:

```
<link href="../polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<polymer-element name="iterative-example">
    <template>

        <!-- Doesn't work -->
        <template repeat="{{ lower, upper in letters }}">
            <p>{{ lower }} and {{ upper }}</p>
        </template>

         <!-- Works -->
        <template repeat="{{ letters in lettersArray }}">
            <p>{{ letters }}</p>
        </template>

    </template>
<script>
    Polymer('iterative-example', {
        letters: {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C'},
        lettersArray: ['a', 'b', 'c']
   });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then in the index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="components/iterative-example.html">
</head>
<body>
    <iterative-example></iterative-example>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I end up with when it renders in the browser:

```
<iterative-example>
    <template repeat="{{ lower, upper in letters }}">
        #document-fragment
    </template>
    <template repeat="{{ letters in lettersArray }}">
        #document-fragment
    </template>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
</iterative-example>
```

Why won't the iteration over the dictionary work?

I have the special blank outer template for the shadow dom.  There aren't any errors being thrown by the console.  According to [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#iterative-templates) I should be able to do it with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can only itereate through array object not object literals. However using following filter trick you can trnasform your object to array

```
    <polymer-element name="iterative-example">
<template>

    <!-- Doesn't work -->
    <template repeat="{{ letter in letters | toArray }}">
        <p>{{ letter.lower }} {{ letter.upper }}</p>
    </template>

     <!-- Works -->
    <template repeat="{{ letters in lettersArray }}">
        <p>{{ letters }}</p>
    </template>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer('iterative-example', {
        letters: {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C'},
        lettersArray: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        toArray:function  (argument) {
            var result = [];
            for (var property in argument) {
                if (argument.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    result.push({lower:property, upper:argument[property]});
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
   });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```